# Checking for defined functions in nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When passing a function into a directive which then is passed into a nested child directive the function is always considered defined when checked in the scope of the child directive regardless if it is passed in or not in the parent directive.

Is there a better way to either pass in function pointers or check if they are defined when dealing with nested directives.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t4wZfivEJ0chvxLBTgoJ?p=info)

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <dir1"></dir1>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dir1">
    <div>
      <dir2 fun="fun()"></dir2>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dir2">
    <div>{{fun()}}</div>
    <div>{{funDefined()}}</div> <!-- always true-->
  </script>
</body>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.fun = function() {
    alert("function");
  };
});

app.directive('dir1', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fun: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'dir1'
  };
});

app.directive('dir2', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fun: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.funDefined = function() {
        return angular.isDefined(attrs.fun);
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'dir2'
  };
});
```

Comment: Well, but it _is_ defined, as far as dir2 is concerned. It is responsibility of the caller to supply correct arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you set debugger inside your `scope.funDefined` method of dir2 you'll see that `attrs.fun` equals string `"fun()"`. That's because you take raw value from attributes. And since it's a not empty string it'll always give you `true`.

Here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HPWDH9U7aQqAxsU7cn8u?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There's no elegant way I know to get what you want. Like it was mentioned before this line:

```
angular.isDefined(attrs.fun)
```

performs check on string so it will return true every time `fun` attribute is defined. And in your dir1 directive template you have `<dir2 fun="fun()"></dir2>` so `fun` is obviously defined (and it's string). If you take a look at angular's sources:

```
case '&':
            // Don't assign Object.prototype method to scope
            parentGet = attrs.hasOwnProperty(attrName) ? $parse(attrs[attrName]) : noop;

            // Don't assign noop to destination if expression is not valid
            if (parentGet === noop && optional) break;

            destination[scopeName] = function(locals) {
              return parentGet(scope, locals);
            };
            break;
```

you'll see that presence of the attribute will always result in some function assigned to the scope (`$parse` returns function even for string that doesn't make much sense).

So the only solution I can think of is to perform check in the first level directive (it's possible there since attribute is really undefined) and have two `<dir2>` tags (with and without `fun` attribute) - one always excluded using `ng-if`. Something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/AOPRHmEMUZ2OZNhTdQjv?p=preview). Again, I know, its ugly solution.

One side note - Angular's source also shows that scope property will not be set if there's no attribute and binding is optional (using `&?`) - then you can check `scope.fun` value instead of `attrs.fun` - some may find it more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find is based in what @xersiee commented in another answer. The idea is to make the scope parameter optional in the parent directive and then use `angular.isUndefined(scope.$parent.$eval(attribute.myFun))` to check if the function was passed or not. This is not explained in the official documentation... I wonder why.

As other people has mentioned, this solution is far from ideal because using scope.$parent is an anti-pattern, but again, this is the best option I could find.

Plunker with this solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/SUUMae?p=preview